# Lucene - Phonetic Filter

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to use the Phonetic Filter (lucene v 4.2.1) for a French application but it's seems like that filter and all the algorithms provided (metaphone,soundex ...) are for English use only.

So here are my questions :

- PhoneticFilter is it compatible for French use ?
- If no, does an alternative exist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language it is compatible with depends entirely on the `Encoder` you pass into the constructor.  A [BeiderMorseEncoder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/BeiderMorseEncoder.html) is designed to handle many languages, including french, and so may be a good choice.

Comment: DoubleMetaphone and Soundex Encoders seems to work approximately, but BeiderMorseEncoder seems better. Thx.